# How to compare two ip address in c?

Tags: c, networking, casting, ip

I am trying to compare ip address and see if it fits in a range (i.e. network id and broadcast id)

```
starting =(rt_walker->dest).s_addr;
subnet = (rt_walker->mask).s_addr;
broadcast = starting | (~subnet);
if(ip_address>=starting && ip_address<=broadcast){
       found_route =1;
 }
```

This code works fine, but if i had "10.0.0.0" for rt_walker->dest then 
this line (rt_walker->dest).s_addr is giving me 10 instead of a 32bit binary value. So, if was comparing "10.0.0.0"(starting address) with "9.90.100.78"(IP_address that is getting compared) it always falls in range(10 - 10.255.255.255) which should not be true.

Comment: Switch the byte order before doing int comparsion

Comment: How do i do that? any help code?

Comment: In an array with four chars a b c d, how do you think you can switch the order to d c b a? Nothing else is this here. http://linux.die.net/man/3/htonl will do it, else manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @deviantfan mentioned in the comments, I just need to have

`htonl((rt_walker->dest).s_addr)`

And it works perfect!!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a quick and easy way to compare two IP addresses:

```
int ipa_match(uint32_t addr1, uint32_t addr2, uint32_t mask)
{
    return !((addr1 ^ addr2) & mask);
}
```

The XOR tells you which bits in the two addresses are different.  The AND tells you if they differ in the masked portion.  And the rest should be self-explanatory.